# What different from long.class and Long.class?

Tags: java, primitive-types, boxing

Could any explain to me this test:

```
assertTrue(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(long.class)); //---> FAILED
assertTrue(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(Long.class)); //---> PASSED
```

So what is the difference between `long.class` and `Long.class`?

Answer (score 4):

In **Java** `long` and `Long` are different types. The first one is a primitive and the second one is a class.

`Long` extends `Number`, but `long` doesn´t.

Comment: ... and since the types are different, so are their corresponding `Class` objects.

Comment: so, there are `Class<long>` and `Class<Long>`?

Comment: primitives (long) are not really classes. You can´t do new long(), new ArrayList<long>, ...   long.class is only allowed in order to determine the type of the variable, in example, long a = 33L; a.class.isPrimitive() returns true.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, class names are case-sensitive and usually starting with a capital letter. Long is a class in Java (called wrapper class) but long it's not. There is no long.cass !

long is a primitive. This means you only have the variable and some operations like +/-*=.
Long is a class that has a long number inside and some functions besides the operators like idk... ToString() (have a look in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)). Wrapping a long primitive in a class makes it a Wrapper Class